# To find out duplicate elements in a linked list

Tags: linked-list

```
void deleteDups(LinkedListNode n)
  HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
  LinkedListNode previous = null;  
  while(n!=null){
    if(set.contains(n.data)){
      previous.next = n.next;  
    }else {
      set.add(n.data);
      previous = n;
    }
    n = n.next;
  }
}
```

This code snippet is to remove duplicate elements in a linked List.

I have been going through the linked list concepts in cracking the coding interview. Since only the code snippet is available I am not able to understand the flow and where the LinkedListNode n in the first line is actually from. I can understand that they are passing the entire linked list as a parameter, it would be helpful if anybody can tell me what the code for that LinkedListNode will be. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  You should read through the [guide to asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as good questions will get more attention.  In this case, I would tag your question with the language, indent the code properly, and give a clearer idea of what you are trying to accomplish.  If its a walkthrough of how this function works, that's really not what stackoverflow will do for you.  Try giving your use case for removing duplicates and what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

LinkedList traversal: Given the head (starting node) of the list, you could traverse the whole list. Each currentnode will have the information of nextnode which can be accessed by current.next.

In your code LinkedListNode 'n' is the starting node (head) of the list where duplicates needs to be removed